# Getting data from a subclass when it is stored in a superclass variable

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to understand the best way to go about this problem. Say we have a **data model Family** which stores a `Pet` variable. I have other classes that *extend* `Pet` such as `Dog`, `Cat`, `Fish` etc. I need to have a `List<Family>` but when I loop through it I need to access the **subclasses** of `Pet`.
Should I have a variable in the `Pet` class which stores the type of pet? Or should I use `instanceof`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instanceof is your friend here, but if you end up with dozen of if-elses, thet i would say that you should rethink your design. Usually in such cases, you would like to iterate over `List<Pet>` and access common methods/fields to all pets, not particular kid of pet (read - particular subtype)

Comment: You need to learn about [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have a List but when I loop through it I need to access the subclasses of Pet.

why?

Class Pet should have common methods that all its subclasses override with special behavior. The code using the list of pets should only call those common methods.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html <- this provides an example of what Timothy is saying.